# Are the GUIs of ChessBase chess programs the same?

Tags: engines, software, computer-chess

ChessBase (the company) has several chess analysis programs available: Fritz, Komodo Chess, Houdini Pro, Deep Junior and Deep Rybka. Do all of these programs use one and the same graphical user interface?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not 100% sure as I only own Fritz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question [Confused about ChessBase](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/9376/1108), the answer by @Apasserby sums the GUIs up nicely:

> Deep Fritz 14, Houdini 4, Komodo 9 and Rybka 4 all use the same Graphic User Interface (GUI).

So yes, ChessBase uses the same GUI.